# How to write to a file column by column where data is coming from different loop?

Tags: python, loops, file, for-loop, file-writing

I'm facing a code problem in my analysis.
I'd like your suggestions and opinions.

I have 3 for loop for looping over 3 arrays (I'm calling them master array_1, 2, 3).
Inside every loop, I'm storing some values (I'm calling them element_1, 2) in some other arrays.
And also I want to store them in a single file. So,

```
for i in master_array_1:
    [Store element_1 of master_array_1 to its array]
    [Store element_2 of master_array_1 to its array]

    file_handle.write(element_1 of master_array_1)
    file_handle.write(" ")
    file_handle.write(element_2 of master_array_1)
    file_handle.write(" \n")
```

Similarly for

```
for i in master_array_2:
    [Store element_1 of master_array_2 to its array]
    [Store element_2 of master_array_2 to its array]

    file_handle.write(element_1 of master_array_2)
    file_handle.write(" ")
    file_handle.write(element_2 of master_array_2)
    file_handle.write(" \n")
```

Similarly for master_array_3.

But I want a file that will show all the elements of all the master arrays side by side. One after another.
Like,

```
element_1_master_1      element_2_master_1       element_1_master_2       element_2_master_2      .......
```

But what I'm doing is not gonna yield that. It will create master_2 columns under master_1 columns.
Is there any technique that I can implement to achieve what I want?
(The length of arrays are not same)

I was thinking creating 3 different files for 3 different loops and then merge them later in a single file.
But that's not my first choice.
I'd like to create all using only a single file.

Comment: You can use `zip()` to combine your arrays into rows.

Comment: also, I suggest you learn about functions so you don't have to repeat the exact same code for each master array.

Comment: Right.  For example, `for i,j,k in zip(master_array_1,master_array_2,master_array_3):`.